# Redirecting to some error page

Tags: php, symfony

```
/**
 * @Route("/installation", name="installation")
 */
public function defaultAction()
{
    $this->checkPhpVersion();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('setdatabase'));
}

private function checkPhpVersion()
{
    if(phpversion() <= '5.5.0') 
    {
        $message = 'aaa';   
        return $this->render('myFooBundle:Bar:error.html.twig', ['message' => $message]);       
    }
}
```

Well, I'd like the if instruction in the `checkPhpVersion()` method to display the error page and stop later executions.

The instruction is being called, but it seems that the view is not rendered properly, because I get redirected to the setdatabase controller (the end of `defaultAction()`), and I shouldn't.

The content of error.html.twig is not being displayed. Instead, as mentioned above, the setdatabase controller is called and its method's view appears.

What's wrong?

---

```
private function checkPhpVersion()
{
    if(phpversion() <= '5.5.0') 
    {
        echo 1;
        exit();
        echo 2;
        $message = 'aaa';  
        return $this->render('myFooBundle:Bar:error.html.twig', ['message' => $message]);     
    }
}
```

This still changes nothing. However, deleting redirect statement and placing raw `return array()` there, deleting `exit()`, displays '1' and '2' integers, and some error according to the `return array()` mentioned.

Comment: are you able to see the message.is your php version is <= '5.5.0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is wrong because you call a function returning a view, and then from the caller you proceed with a redirect (so both actions are triggered).

One solution would be to adapt your `checkPhpVersion()` function as follow:

```
/**
 * @Route("/installation", name="installation")
 */
public function defaultAction()
{
    if (!is_null($message = $this->checkPhpVersion()))
      return $this->render('myFooBundle:Bar:error.html.twig', ['message' => $message]);
    else
      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('setdatabase'));
}

private function checkPhpVersion()
{
    return phpversion() <= '5.5.0' ? 'aaa' : null;
}
```

If you want to leave the view generation inside the `checkPhpVersion()` function, you can use:

```
/**
 * @Route("/installation", name="installation")
 */
public function defaultAction()
{
    if(!empty($this->checkPhpVersion()))
      return new Response($content);
    else
      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('setdatabase'));
}

private function checkPhpVersion()
{
    if(phpversion() <= '5.5.0') 
    {
        $message = 'aaa';   
        return $this->renderView('myFooBundle:Bar:error.html.twig', ['message' => $message]);       
    }
}
```

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#rendering-templates

Comment: The function would get too long if I had more checking to do...is there some cleaner way?

Comment: See my edit if it helps! (note that `render` becomes `renderView`)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to stop further execution, use the PHP [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) function in your `checkPhpVersion` method after rendering the error page.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Adding exit() before and/or after return statement doesn't change anything in this case.